# Prevent navigation in the source tree on tab click - Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to prevent the navigation in the source tree while clicking on some tab ?

I'm working on 5 tabs, and every time I click on some particular tab, VS Code navigates me to the location of that file, in the source tree.
I want to prevent that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
"explorer.autoReveal": false
```

Related to this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3062)